# Mixed model with crossed effects and repeated measures - what is correct ‘maximal model’ for use in lmer/lme4? [R]

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

**Objective**

I have a crossed and implicitly nested design and am trying to validate the correct ‘maximal’ model (including all linear and pairwise interactions of the variables) for use in `lmer()`.  I intend to use this as the starting point for some kind of backward stepwise regression, possibly making use of the function `mixed()` in the  `{afex}` package.

**Experimental design**

This a linguistics study.  We have 20 `Subjects`, each speaking 180 utterances, amounting to 3600 observations in total. Each utterance is initiated via prompting, and an associated Response Time is measured. Log Response Time is the dependent variable.

*Conditions & Blocks*

The Response Time for the utterances is affected by 3 `Conditions` (coded 1 to 3). Each `Condition` is implemented by prompting the `Subject` to recite 1 of 4 `Blocks` of utterances (coded 1 to 12).

*Words & Tones*

Each `Block` brings about its associated `Condition` via 15-utterance repetition of 3 carefully chosen `Words`.  There are a total of 12 `Words` used in the experiment (coded 1 to 12). The `Words` within each `Block` can also be categorized by `Tone` (coded 1 to 2).  There are 6 `Words` per `Tone`.

*Summary*

Each of the 20 `Subjects` utter all 12 `Blocks` of 15 utterances each.  In doing so, they repeatedly utter all 12 `Words` (15 utterances per `Word`), and thereby use both `Tones` (90 utterances per `Tone`).

I would like to consider `Block`, `Word`, and `Subject` as random effects, and `Condition` and `Tone` as fixed.

**Proposed Model**

I think the model can be written in the following way…

`RT_log ~ Condition*Tone + (Condition*Tone|Subject) + (Condition|Word) + (Tone|Block)`

**Questions**

**1.** Is this the 'maximal' model (with linear plus pairwise interactions) appropriate for my experimental design?_

**2.** There is correlation between `Block` and `Condition` (there are only 4 possible blocks - out of the total 12 - for each `Condition`).  There is, similarly, correlation between `Word` and `Tone`.  Is it 'okay' to leave this correlation in the model? I don't see a good way of removing it.

**3.** How will lme4 handle implicit nesting: I.e., the blocks, which are implicitly nested in the 3 conditions (i.e., only 4 blocks are applicable to each of the 3 conditions, even though the blocks are coded from 1 to 12), and the words, which are implicitly nested within the 2 tones (only 6 words are applicable to each tone, even though words are coded from 1 to 12)?

**4.** Some `Blocks` utilize `Words` of only a single `Tone`, whereas other `Blocks` utilize words of both `Tones`.  Will that cause problems for the `(Tone|Block)` term in the model? It will only make sense for certain values of Block.

**5.** It has been suggested by some that we might need a "Subject:Word" grouping (random effect).  Why might we need this grouping?

Comment: I am very skeptical about the *keeping-it-maximal* rationale. It really seems like one over-parameterizes a model. From a practical standpoint there are a lot of parameters to estimate. From a theoretical standpoint one tests against really spurious phenomena. Such models are often singular and having problematic convergence (something that it is a essential for this "maximal" rationale to work). Check [Bates at al. 2015](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04967) for more.

Comment: Thanks.  I am only looking for maximal as a starting point...guidance for which terms to investigate.

Comment: @user11852, do you have any thoughts regarding the specific terms I have listed or not listed?  I am totally new to lmer modeling and to mixed-effects modeling, so any thoughts along these lines would be much appreciated.

Comment: Given you have recognised three terms as random I would start with those. At first instance I would use a fully crossed design between `Subject`, `Word` and `Block` (so something like) `...+ (1|Subject) + (1|Word) + (1|Block)` and see were this takes me, what are the estimated variance amplitude, etc. I would avoid using `Tone` in any of the r.e. structures.

Comment: Additional comment: Surely some effect for a grouping `Subject:Word` can be present. By definition none of the variables are orthogonal to each other. I am pretty sure that you might be able to argue a `Subject:Block:Word` grouping too, but what good is that for your research question?

Comment: @user11852, how would a "Subject:Word" grouping be interpreted by lmer?  "Word" is not really "nested" within subject - all the words are the same (and therefore comparable) across Subjects.  (I ask not because I am gung-ho about adding this grouping to the model, but because I am not familiar with lmer syntax in this respect.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35055/discussion-between-usr11852-and-clarpaul).